# React js application isn't running on localhost:3000

Tags: reactjs, localhost

I have tried many many times but my http://localhost:3000 not working at all.

Just taking **reload** & **reload**

Console log is also clear. nothing at there.

1st time when I faced this problem, I cleared the history, then it works but now this is not working,

After giving so much pressure, it shows me,**"**

**Aw, Snap!**

```
something went wrong while displaying this webpage.
```

"

*my app.js file:*

```
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">

      <h1>Hello World</h1>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

*my package.json file:*

```
{
  "name": "secret-name",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.1.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Just the **`title`** of my website appears at the **`top`**.

I can't create a new react app because this is an assignment and I have pushed the primary code to the private repository. I don't want more problems.

After facing this problem, I deleted the package.lock.json & node_modules and then again install the packages by npm install.

What can I do now?

Comment: Well, check the browser console. Perhaps you mess up something in your code. I don't think anyone will be able to give you an answer with so little information you provided at this point.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This issue is occurring with React 18, but instead of when you try either the network ip or the 127.0.0.1:3000 or port change 3001 also, it will work, I faced the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think that something went wrong when you create the project.
Try to create a new one

```
npx create-react-app my_app_name
```

And the run

```
npm run start
```